# Installation problems with windows 8

Tags: installation

Ok so i am running windows 8 on my computer currently and trying to get Ubuntu up and running in a dual boot.  My system has UEFI secure boot (for the record its a laptop).  When i boot up my Ubuntu from a flash drive it does not recognize windows 8 is installed on my system.  Also if it is any help, Windows 8 and the drive i am try to install Ubuntu on is a solid state drive.  And before anyone asks i have trying disabling secure boot.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-system-uefi-supported

Answer (score 0):

You should turn off UEFI secure boot when installing Ubuntu and turn on it later.

You can just mount on some partitions (/dev/sdaN) and check which partition contain Windows.

For partitioning for Ubuntu, execute `GParted` in your Terminal window and make partiton and some space for Ubuntu.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu manually  by partitioning, i was just kinda wondering if anyone could shed some light on why it can not detect my operating system.  It would make boot management a lot easier